# How can I (using google api client for uploading documents to google drive) set the share links to public?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I have some code that I'm working on to automatically upload files from a computer to google drive. I'm already getting a link (see below) but am still not able to set the link to public view so that anyone could view the link. It's currently set to private and I've looked around but just haven't found anything on how to set the link of the uploaded file to public. I've also tried adding the type anyone role reader parameters but nothing seems to work.

```
import os 
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


class GoogleDriveHelper:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
        self.creds = None

    def authenticate(self):
        if os.path.exists("token.json"):
            self.creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", self.scope)

        if not self.creds or not self.creds.valid:
            if self.creds and self.creds.expired and self.creds.refresh_token:
                self.creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    "credentials.json", self.scope
                )
                self.creds = flow.run_local_server()

            with open("token.json", "w") as token:
                token.write(self.creds.to_json())

    def create_folder(self):
        try:
            service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=self.creds)

            response = service.files().list(
                q=F"name='{self.file_name}' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                spaces="drive"
            ).execute()

            if not response["files"]:
                file_metadata = {
                    "name": f"{self.file_name}",
                    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
                    "permissions": [
                        {
                            "type": "anyone",
                            "role": "reader"
                        }
                    ]
                }

                file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields="id").execute()
                folder_id = file.get("id")

                print("Folder created: " + folder_id)

            else:
                folder_id = response["files"][0]["id"]
                print("Folder already created, ID: " + folder_id)

            # Get the web view link for the folder
            file = service.files().get(fileId=folder_id, fields="webViewLink").execute()
            folder_link = file.get("webViewLink")
            print("Folder link: " + folder_link)

            return folder_id, folder_link

        except HttpError as error:
            print(f"Error: {str(error)}")
            return None

    def upload_file(self, file_path, folder_id):
        try:
            service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=self.creds)

            file_metadata = {
                "name": os.path.basename(file_path),
                "parents": [folder_id]
            }

            media = MediaFileUpload(file_path)

            file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id").execute()
            file_id = file.get("id")

            print("File uploaded: " + file_id)

            return file_id

        except HttpError as error:
            print(f"Error: {str(error)}")
            return None
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The webViewLink is the link that any one with access to the file can use to view the file within their google drive account.

If you want someone to be able to access it your going to have to grant them permissions. using permission.insert and their email address.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I eanted to know if I could set the permissions to anyone can view the link

Comment: you can't you need to add people as I mentioned